# What are the CSS prefixes for all the possible CSS attributes that you know so far?

Tags: css, frontend

Can a CSS expert tell me, what are the CSS prefixes available for all the possible CSS attributes so far? I have searched this on the web, yet couldn't find a good answer. 
for example, the display flex doesn't support on all the browsers Right, so we have to put prefixes like **display:-webkit-flex**. so I wanna know all the prefixes of CSS attributes.

```
.div{
display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

These are the main vendor prefixes, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_hack#Browser_prefixes)